# hibernate manually control object construction

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate assumes all object member are comes from the SQL database it in charge. What if some field of an object which not comes from SQL, for example, the data source is another NoSQL database or just file.

```
    class A {
        public B b;
        public A(int bId) {
            //b object is in an self defined cache which the 
            //data source is not SQL beneath hibernate
            b = CacheOfB.get(bId); 
        }
    }

    class B {
        int id;
        int other_property;
    }
```

So if I add `@Embeddable` to B, let A's table contain an field of b_id, hibernate will fail to init the b member in A.

It seems there is no way to self define constructor, however, it can be done by 2 phase construct like:

```
class A {
    @Transient
    public B b;
    @Column(name="b_id")
    private int bId;
    void initMemberB() {
        this.b = CacheOfB.get(bId);
    }
}
A a = session.get(A.class, aId);
a.initMemberB();
```

But this is ugly, so, any better solution?

Answer (score 1):

I found jpa annotation @PostLoad, @PrePersist works.

```
class A {
    @Transient
    public B b;
    @Column(name="b_id")
    private int bId;
    @PostLoad
    private void initMemberB() {
        this.b = CacheOfB.get(bId);
    }
    @PrePersist
    private void setBId() {
        this.bId = this.b.id;
    }
}
A a = session.get(A.class, aId);
assert a.b.id == a.bId;
```

However, this still is 2 phase construction, however the steps are hidden. I think this is the best effort jpa/hibernate can achieve.